# custom URL scheme does not work when app is not running in background

Tags: ios, custom-url

I am calling a custom URL from safari to launch an app. It works fine if the app is running in background. But when the app is not running in background , but is already installed on the device, the app does not launch. I have implemented both of the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

but none of them is called when app is not running in background.

Also I have googled and found that we can launch the app using the following code when app is not running in background

```
if ( [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] != nil ) {
    NSURL *url =(NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    [self application:application handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

But unfortunately , **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is also not triggered. Does some one has any pointers?

P.S : This problem occurs only in iPad.It works fine on iPhone.

Comment: did u add the UIApplicationDelegate in AppDelegate.h?

Comment: @manujmv.. Yes, I did.

Answer (score 3):

i was facing the same problem.

Seems that our code was running too fast.

Inserting a delay to run your custom code will resolve the issue.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(yourCustomActions) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you please explain how delay can work out. Its working but I want to know the  reason behind this.

Comment: @iProgrammer i'm not sure. I guess when we give the app the 0,5 second delay, when "yourCustomActions" runs the app has already finished the process of being active.

Answer (score 0):

Got to your info.plist and perform the necessary changes

1. Add new row --> URL types
2. expand it
3. in item 0 add new row ---> URL Schemes
4. expand it
5. In Item 0 under it, add the custom url you want to use
6. add one row under item 0 of urlTypes --> URL identifier
7. provide the bundle id of your app there

eg: anubhab://stackoverflow.com/

for the above custom url you would set the URL Scheme item 0 as:
anubhab

see the image attached for detail
[image]

I have followed these [link](http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-18%E2%80%93Opening-your-App-from-a-Website). Hope it helps. It works fine for me even if I kill the app from background.

Wayback machine version of that link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170707150909/http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS-Day-18-Opening-your-App-from-a-Website.

Comment: I have already done these changes. That is why it runs properly when the app is running in background. My problem is when app is not running, then it does not launch the app.

Comment: i Have edited the answer with a link. please check it out. If it helps. It does work fine with me.

Comment: @ManiacOne The link is down. Could you explain how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

When another app opens a URL containing your custom scheme, the system **launches your app, if necessary**, and brings it to the foreground. The system delivers the URL to your app by calling your app delegate’s application(_:open: options:)

override The following function in the app delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool {



    // Process the URL.
    guard let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
        let albumPath = components.path,
        let params = components.queryItems else {
            print("Invalid URL or album path missing")
            return false
    }
}
```

[apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app)