# Can URL Scheme Launch Same App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I want to launch my App once it goes to background. I have used following code:

```
NSString *customURL = @"TestApp://?caller=TestApp%3A%2F%2Fblabla";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}

else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"URL error"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                             @"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL]
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

But it is working fine in simulator but it is not working in iOS Device: I have tested in iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.3

Please guide me if any things extra we need to do.
Here TestApp is URL Schemes I have put in my info.plist file.

Comment: You have to specify the URL it's listening to in the `-info.plist` file. Done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385542/custom-url-scheme-does-not-work-when-app-is-not-running-in-background check this link it will help you..:)

Comment: I couldn't say I would be surprised if Apple prevented you bringing the app to the foreground without user interaction. Interesting idea though...

Comment: Yes I have set everything in info.plist. In device I am getting below warning.

Comment: Feb 26 13:15:32 iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: [FBSystemService] Error launching URL for com.abc.xyz: Security (3)
Feb 26 13:15:32 iPhone lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: application launch failed - received error Security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't open your own app using URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8.x onwards, installing app from other sources e.g. from your company's website for QA testing or from somewhere else, will show an alert "Untrusted App Developer" that identifies it is coming from an Untrusted App Developer"

Application shows this message because the application is signed via an enterprise certificate that has not yet been trusted by the user. Apple force this prompt to appear because the application that is being installed hasn't gone through the App Store review process so is technically untrusted.
Once the user has accepted the prompt, the certificate will be marked as trusted. 
Once app trusted, you can open your app using URL Scheme Launch.

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting an error ( : LaunchServices: application launch failed - received error Security )

Try this -

1. Install app.
2. Launch app via normal app shortcut.
3. Hit 'trust' if the pop up opens.
4. Kill process
5. Try launching process via URL/Bookmark